# ¿Por qué es usado el subjuntivo en "aunque eso no significaba que me hubiesen olvidado"?

Tags: subjuntivo

En el texto:

> Las noticias eran buenas: la situación en mi casa era normal y mis perseguidores no habían dado señales de vida, **aunque eso no significaba que me hubiesen olvidado**.

Aquí, el verbo subordinado por *aunque* es indicativo y en consecuencia el autor cree que es verdad. No obstante, el verbo sub-subordinado en subjuntivo me preocupa. La razón más clara que puedo postular es que indica un oracion causal en que el hablante que hable en indicativo simpatiza con un hecho cuando describe un motivo o causa, pero no compadece o se muestra imparcial cuando habla en subjuntivo. Aquí por seguro no está de acuerdo con los perseguidores y la explicacion que ellos no la han olvidado a pesar de la falta de evidencia puede ser en subjuntivo para expresar el desacuerdo.

He encontrado ejemplos del (para mí) oscuro uso de oraciones causales que puede encontrar en [El subjuntivo en subordinadas adverbiales](http://www1.udel.edu/leipzig/depende/subj_adverbiales.htm).

> Dicho esto, quiero añadir que la huelga del 27-E me parece legítima
> pero inútil, y no porque González **haya decidido** no moverse aunque sea
> un éxito, ni porque comparta lo del gran daño para la economía ni
> porque me guste la reforma laboral.
>
> Es una herencia del pasado. Por
> motivos de política general, este año los presupuestos apenas han
> aumentado. Se ha seguido con la inercia del pasado, por lo que ha
> salido primado el Reina Sofía frente al Prado. Lo que sí tengo que
> decir es que el presupuesto del Prado es de 2.378 millones pero que
> también va a recibir los 1.500 millones del arreglo de las cubiertas y
> lo que cueste toda la ampliación. Sin duda, cuando los presupuestos
> sean más flexibles, tendrá que actualizarse también el del Prado. No
> lo digo porque **me guste** más la pintura antigua que la contemporánea, y
> porque también **la haya estudiado** más, es que creo que...

Segunda hipótesis: La narradora cree que en verdad la falta de signos significa nada, y por lo tanto ellos quizá la hayan olvidado pero es dudable.

Comment: No entiendo el uso de _conforme_ en la frase _indica un oracion causal en que el hablante se conforme con un hecho cuando describe un motivo o causa_. ¿Podrías explicarlo?

Comment: @fedorqui Yo quería decir el hablante está de acuerdo con...

Comment: Gracias, user, ahora entiendo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Aunque* funciona bien con subjuntivo bien con indicativo (solo que con el subjuntivo tiene la connotación de «sea que es o no»).  En este caso, veamos la diferencia:

> …la situación en mi casa era normal y mis perseguidores no habían dado señales de vida, **aunque eso no significaba**… <sub>(no lo habríamos esperado, pero que conste no significaba)</sub>
>
> …la situación en mi casa era normal y mis perseguidores no habían dado señales de vida, **aunque eso no significa<sup>ra</sup>/<sub>se</sub>**… <sub>(a pesar de que o incluso en el caso de que no significase)</sub>

Pero tu pregunta radica en la última parte que no depende de la conjunción *aunque* porque es una cláusula nominal que es complemente del verbo *significar*.  Visto así, creo que debe ser fácil entender por qué se usa el subjuntivo: cuando decimos que algo *significa* algo, estamos afirmando ese segundo algo.  No obstante, cuando decimos que algo ***no** significa* algo, estamos rechazando la idea del segundo algo.  Ese rechazo o negación induce el subjuntivo.

Comment: @fedorqui alguien cambió el CSS?  parece que `<sub></sub>`  ya no sale bien.

Comment: Mmmm yo lo veo bien.

Comment: @fedorqui en el móvil me sale bien, pero en el ordenador salía (mañana lo pruebo de nuevo para ver si sigue) solo con tamaño más pequeño y no subido/bajado)

Comment: Qué raro. En mi ordenador uso Google Chrome 58 y sale así: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlRbl.png

Answer (score 2):

*Con esta respuesta voy a tratar de complementar la de guifa.*

La siguiente oración sería muy correcta:

> Mis perseguidores no daban señales de vida en ese momento, pero, como al poco descubrí, no me habían olvidado.

Pero no se puede escribir así:

> Mis perseguidores no habían dado señales de vida, aunque eso no significaba que me habían olvidado.

porque *NO* significaba que la hubieran olvidado.  Es decir, la negación requiere el subjuntivo.